# Undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, makefile

I am getting an unexpected error while compiling a c++ program using makefile

I'm getting the following error:

```
ishant@russell:~/CSD/cache$ make
make: Warning: File `makefile' has modification time 1.6e+03 s in the future
\g++ -o naivea.out naive.cpp mycache.cpp mylru.cpp myblock.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [naive] Error 1
```

My makefile:

```
CC = \g++
CFLAGS = -W -Wall
COMMON = mycache.cpp mylru.cpp myblock.cpp
NAIVE = results/naive/
AWARE = results/aware/

all : naive aware 

naive : naive.cpp $(COMMON)
    $(CC) -o $(NAIVE)a.out $^

aware : cacheaware.cpp $(COMMON)
    $(CC) -o $(AWARE)a.out $^ -lm
```

mycache.cpp, mylru.cpp and myblock.cpp have definitions for methods in class cache, lru and block respectively. While cacheaware.cpp and naive.cpp have code for matrix multiplication and also the main() function

Comment: Prove that there's a `main()` in there.

Comment: Also: replace `$(NAIVE)a.out` with `$(NAIVE)/a.out` and `$(AWARE)a.out` with `$(AWARE)/a.out` -- it seems that make removes the trailing slash from `NAIVE` and `AWARE`

Comment: Also check that your `main` functions have the correct signature, i.e. `int main(int, char**)`

Comment: The output you show above doesn't seem to match your Makefile.  Specifically, `$(NAIVE)` is set to `results/naive/`, but the G++ command line shows that `$(NAIVE)a.out` expanded to `naivea.out`, which makes no sense.  I also echo @arne's suggestion that you check `main`'s signature.  In C++ under POSIX, I believe it must be one of `int main()`, `int main(void)`, `int main(int, char**)`, or `int main(int, char**, char**)`.  (The last one is a POSIX extension.)

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I should be able to work it out now :)